# Docker Reactコンテナを起動するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Tags: docker, reactjs, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

DockerでReact環境を構築しています。
1つ目は問題なく作成することができましたが、2つ目がなぜができません。

**実行環境**
Windows10 Home
Docker(Toolbox)

**コンテナ**
1つ目: node_app_1 (`-p 3000:3000`)
2つ目: react-flux_app_1 (`-p 3001;3000`)

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:  
    app: 
        build: .
        environment: 
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        volumes:
            - ./work:/app
        command: sh -c "cd sample && yarn start"
        ports:
           - '3000:3000'
```

`docker-compose build` 実行後 `docker-compose run --rm app sh -c 'npx create-react-app sample'` を実行し、問題なくReactアプリケーションが作成できます。

また、`docker-compose up` を実行して1つ目のコンテナは問題なく立ち上げることができたのですが、2つ目のコンテナのポートを`'3001:3000'`として作成して`docker-compose up`を実行すると以下のようなメッセージが表示されコンテナが立ち上がりません。
(1つ目のコンテナは立ち上げてても、立ち上げてなくても結果は同じでした。)

```
app_1  | yarn run v1.21.1
app_1  | $ react-scripts start
app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.22.0.2/
app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/sample/public
app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
app_1  | Starting the development server...
app_1  |
app_1  | Done in 17.32s.
react-flux_app_1 exited with code 0
```

となってしまい、コンテナがたちあがってくれません。
エラーらしき内容も見当たらず困り果てています。

なにか問題があればご教授していただけないでしょうか？

<補足>
1つ目のコンテナは問題なく起動して、コンソールは

```
    app_1  | yarn run v1.21.1
    app_1  | $ react-scripts start
    app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.22.0.2/
    app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
    app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/sample/public
    app_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
```

が表示されます。

<補足2>
`docker-compose run --rm app sh -c 'cd sample && yarn start' -p 3333:3000`
を実行すると起動はできましたが`http://192.168.99.100:3333/index.html`は繋がらなかったです。

<補足3>
数の問題ではない気がしてきました。
本日まっさらな環境で1から作ってみましたが、`docker-compose up -d`では起動してくれませんでした・・・が、`docker-compose run --service-ports app`で立ち上げたところすんなり起動してくれました・・・。

Comment: 「1 つ目のコンテナ」というのはどれを指していますか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu♦コンテナについての説明を実行環境の下に追加しました！(コメントありがとうございます！)

Comment: 問題が起きるのは「2つ同時」に起動したときですか？それとも「2つ目を単独」でもNGなのでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick　「2つ目を単独」でNGでした・・・。(コメントありがとうございます！)